# Pygame não está a desenhar um objecto

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

Estou a fazer um jogo no python usando pygame. O jogo consiste num jogador que dispara pequenas balas em função da posição do rato e dele mesmo. Corre tudo na perfeição, o jogador movimenta-se como eu quero, o programa regista direito a posição do rato, quando clico no ESPAÇO o programa lê-o e "dispara" uma bala, faz todos os cálculos da bala corretos… O único problema é que a bala não aparece no ecrã, já testei a função onde a bala é "desenhada" e a função que determina a posição da bala e estão a ser lidas corretamente. Aqui está o código que considero importante:

**Código da bala**

```
class Bullet:
    doDraw = False
    def __init__(self, startx, starty, endx, endy):
        self.startx = startx
        self.starty = starty
        self.endx = endx
        self.endy = endy
        self.framenum = 0
        self.shootBullet()

    def shootBullet(self):
        self.declive = (self.endy-self.starty) / (self.endx-self.startx)
        self.bulletx = self.startx
        self.bullety = self.starty
        self.doDraw = True

    def draw(self):
        self.GetPosition()
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (200, 200, 25), pygame.Rect(self.bulletx, self.bullety, 10, 10))


    def GetPosition(self):
        self.framenum += 1
        if self.endx > self.startx:
            self.bulletx += 1*self.framenum 
        elif self.endx < self.startx:
            self.bulletx -= 1*self.framenum
        self.bullety += self.declive*self.framenum
        if self.bulletx < 0 or self.bulletx > 800 or self.bullety < 0 or self.bullety > 600:
            self.stop()

    def stop(self):
        self.doDraw = False
```

**Código no Main Loop**

```
if keyPressed[pygame.K_SPACE]:
    if 'bullet' in globals():
        if bullet.doDraw == False:
            bullet = Bullet(p.x, p.y, mousePoint[0], mousePoint[1])
            bullet.doDraw = True
    else:
        bullet = Bullet(p.x, p.y, mousePoint[0], mousePoint[1])
        bullet.doDraw = True

if 'bullet' in globals():
    if bullet.doDraw == True:
        bullet.draw()
```

Comment: Quem deu o downvote na questão, por favor, a idea de downvotes não é "eu não sei responder então vou dar um voto negativo". O trecho de código está conciso - está sim faltando alguma coisa para ser executável em separado (a inicialização do screen, e o código do mainloop), mas os trechos de código aí estão bem claros, não tem mais do que precisa, e permite dizer bastante coisa sobre o que acontece.

Answer (score 1):

Você não colocou todo o código do mainloop  - mas muito provavelmente o único problema é que você está a usar uma variável "global" para Bullet, mas do jeito errado.

Quando há necessidade de uma variável global, ela deve ser declarada no começo da função como global, e então ser usada normalmente:

```
bullet = Bullet()
...
def principal():
    global bullet
    ...
    if bullet.doDraw == False:
```

Da forma como está feito, a condição `if 'bullet' in globals():` pode ser verdadeira, mas se `bullet` não está declarada como `global` dentro da função, o programa vai criar uma variável local `bullet` - que pode não ser o que o programa "enxerga" em outras funções.

O problema maior é que aparentemente não há uma  `bullet` em `globals()` quando o mainloop começa, então a condição  `if 'bullet' in globals():` vai ser sempre falsa - e aí ele vai criar uma nova `Bullet` local, mas na parte que desenha:

```
if 'bullet' in globals():
    if bullet.doDraw == True:
        bullet.draw()
```

ele nunca vai entrar (já que a condição será falsa)

A sugestão é:

1. esqueça essa checagem `in globals()` - isso é só errado.
2. Use uma variável local, com o conteúdo `None`, criada no começo do seu mainloop:

```
def principal():
     bullet = None
     ...
     while True:
         ... # código do mainloop
```

3. Não fique testando se a variável existe, apenas se ela tem "None" ou
   uma Bullet já existente:

```
if keyPressed[pygame.K_SPACE]:
    if bullet and not bullet.doDraw:  
         # Use "not variavel" em condiçoes, nunca "variavel == False"
         bullet = Bullet(p.x, p.y, mousePoint[0], mousePoint[1])
         bullet.doDraw = True
         # não precisa do "else" - se a bala já existe e está ativa,
         # não faz nada.

    ...
    # e para desenhar: 
    if bullet and bullet.doDraw == True:
        bullet.draw()
```

Depois de funcionar isso, dê uma olhada na classe "Sprite" do pyagame e nos "groups": o pygame pode gerenciar automaticamente o ciclo de vida das suas balas (em vez de "toDraw=False"  ela poderá chamar `self.kill()` quando chegar ao final da tela, por exemplo, e será removida automaticamente do grupo)  - isso vai permitir uma lógica mais limpa para ter mais de uma bala na tela de cada vez.

Comment: O problema é que, usando o meu código, se eu colocar print("Bala desenhada") na função draw da class bullet, a mensagem é escrita até que a bala saia fora do ecrã, a sua explicação ajudou-me bastante a melhorar o meu código à mesma mas o objeto continua a não ser desenhado, tenho outra classe, que tem uma função draw que tem exatamente a mesma linha de código pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 255, 255), pygame.Rect(50, 50, 25, 25)) e funciona perfeitamente bem..

Comment: Sem ver o códgo todo - em particular como você está definindo `screen` e como estão sendo desenhadas as outras coisas, não consigo ter mais ideias.

Comment: O screen está definido simplesmente por screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600)), os outros objetos estão sendo desenhados da mesma forma que a bala, por exemplo, p.draw() com a função sendo def draw(self): pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 255, 255), pygame.Rect(self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height)) ….